# Yum Corrupted on RHEL 6

Tags: linux, rhel, yum, python

. I am encountering the issue with my yum command. It seems to be exactly the same as the issue described on this site,  [Yum corrupted on CentOS 6.2, Problem importing one the python modules](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/yum-corrupted-on-centos-6-2-problem-importing-one-the-python-modules-4175445270/)

This will be the error produced whenever I execute the yum command.

```
[root@Server1~]# yum list

 There was a problem importing one of the
 Python modules required to run yum. The error leading to this problem
 was:

    /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2: undefined symbol: ber_sockbuf_io_udp

 Please install a package which provides this module, or verify that
 the module is installed correctly.

 It's possible that the above module doesn't match the current version
 of Python, which is:
 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)]

 If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to the yum faq
 at:   http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

However I am able to run # python2 , which is located in `/usr/bin/python2`

```
[root@Server1~]# python2

Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 21 2013, 10:50:32)

[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

\>>>
```

These are the modules yum import:

[image: yum_modules]

Comment: This isn't corruption, it is a linking error, and should be fixaible. From the error message, it sounds like the problem is with one of the Python modules. You'll need to narrow it down. What modules does yum import?

Comment: Look at yum (it's probably a Python script) and try to import the listed modules one by one into the Python interpreter. Please give some details about your Python installation. Is it the default version for your distribution, and if not, have you altered it? In particular, have you done any local installs of Python libraries?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I had updated the yum modules in my question. The default version is Python 3.3.2  as it is required to run some programs. I tried local re-install of openldap, python-ldap, python 2.6.6 and tried confiurging the default back to Python 2.6.6, but the same errors persist. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like the problem is pycurl (from your traceback). You can confirm this by entering `import pycurl` into your Python interpreter. Doing local installs of packages required for system use can break things. I suggest you revert to the defaults for your system (the distribution binary packages) with regard to the libraries (Python or otherwise) that yum uses.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I am not very sure what do you meant by reverting to defaults for the distribution binary packages? Are you referring to change the default python from python3 to python2? Actually I have other servers can are able to work properly with the exact same configuration and the their default python is also python3.  Thats why I am unable to figure out wthat is wrong with this particular server. Is it due to symlink , PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH? 

The server is able to perform yum when I use #LD_LIBRARY_PATH="" 
However I am not suppose to change the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the /etc/profile.

Comment: Ok, first tell me what you see when you do `import pycurl` in  your interpreter. Do you see the same traceback? And yes, when I said reverting to default, I meant use `python2` as the default python if that was the case originally. You write "other servers can are able to work properly with the exact same configuration and the their default python is also python3". That's surprising. You mean you replaced the default python 2 with python 3 and there was no problem? In general, you don't want to do that. Most distributions will allow side by side installations of python 2 and python 3.

Comment: Isn't that good enough for you? Replacing default installations is generally a recipe for breakage, because Linux systems depend on their default Python version to run properly.

Comment: BTW, text should be preferred to screenshots of text. You can't search for the text in a screenshot, and you can't cut and paste them.

Comment: @FaheemMitha yes import pycurl gives the same error. Originally the all the system default python is python2. After installation of python3, the default of python in all system were change to python3 automatically, and there is no issue with other system except this. All these systems have the same LD_LIBRARY_PATH in /etc/profile.

Sorry about it, I wanted to paste text too but the format made it crumble up here, thus I thought it would be easier for viewing with screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22456/discussion-between-win-t-and-faheem-mitha).

Comment: Let's use the main U&L chat room. It is usually not too busy, and occasionally other people can be persuaded to take an interest. I always have it open. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux You can ping me from there.

Answer (score 0):

You should do `ldd /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2`, check output for 'undefined references', find package which provides that undefined lib, find your repo, manually download the rpm which provides that lib, install it with `rpm -i <missing>.rpm`.

Most probably your problem is due to bug in libldap or your manual intervention into packaging system.

I happen to have RHEL6 nearby, so let's find your symbol`for lib in /lib64/*.so.*; do if nm -D $lib|grep ber_sockbuf_io_udp; then    echo $lib; fi; done`

returns:

```
0000003e2240e460 D ber_sockbuf_io_udp
 /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2
0000003e2240e460 D ber_sockbuf_io_udp
/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.5.6
                U ber_sockbuf_io_udp
/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2
                 U ber_sockbuf_io_udp
/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2.5.6
                 U ber_sockbuf_io_udp
/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
                 U ber_sockbuf_io_udp
/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.5.6
```

So your symbol defined in /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2, which is installed on my system. As it is installed I could do `rpm -qf /lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2` which show me

```
openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.x86_64
```

So it should be part of your package. Now your should check if this library exists in your fs. If it doesn't - download and reinstall the openldap package. If it does exist - something wrong with your python.

Comment: thanks for your help. I had tried all the following you mentioned. There is no 'undefined references', the return for the for loop has also the same output, and openldap package is also availble. I had reinstall both python2 and openldap locally, but does not work either. If you mention that its thats something wrong with the python, it doesn't seems to be as I am able to execute python2 using # python2; and it works perfectly; only thing is my yum not working, keeping giving me this error: /lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2: undefined symbol: ber_sockbuf_io_udp

Comment: noted, I will try when back office and let you know.. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: No actually i am not right. This is python trying to load c++ module (who knows how it does it). Use ` ls /usr/lib64/*/site-packages/*.so| while read lib; do echo $lib':'; ldd $lib|grep ldap; done` to find out which module require that symbol. It seem commentators above right and this is pycurl. Simplest way would be to deinstall that module, depending on how did you installed it. If with rpm use something like `rpm -qf /usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/_audit.so` to find package and rpm -r to uninstall it.

Comment: I had tried out re-installing the modeule libldap-2.4.so.2 from the latest package openldap-2.4.39-8.el6.i686, it does not help. :(
ermm..wonder what is wrong with this issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case (RHEL7.8 + Apache 2.4 + Shibboleth 3.2) I was able to resolve the issue by replacing the `/usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2` library with the one from the Apache directory: `<APACHE_ROOT>/HTTPServer/openldap/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2`

Run:
`locate libldap_r-2.4.so.2`
to find the location of the library.
In my case I got:

```
/app/ptc/Windchill_12.0/HTTPServer/openldap/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
/app/ptc/Windchill_12.0/HTTPServer/openldap/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.12
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
/usr/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.7
/usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
/usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.7
```

I noticed that the lib used in the error was in `/usr/lib64` dir.
I replaced it and now `./apachectl -t` reports
"Syntax OK"

I don't know enough about Linux to explain what is going on here or what the correct fix is.
This was my observation and resolved the issue, I believe my steps are a hack though.

Anyone with a more elegant, upgrade proof solution?

Reference: https://groups.google.com/g/repmgr/c/TS7QfYEoNoY

```
cd /usr/lib64/
ll | grep libldap
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       21 Feb 11 16:42 libldap-2.4.so.2 -> libldap-2.4.so.2.10.7
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   352512 Jun  6  2020 libldap-2.4.so.2.10.7
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root       23 Feb 11 16:42 libldap_r-2.4.so.2 -> libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.7
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root   381328 Jun  6  2020 libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.7
```

It does seem like `/usr/lib64/libldap_r2.4.so.2` is just a symlink to `libldap_r-2.4.so.2.10.7`.

I wonder if there are missing or deprecated symbols in 2.10.7...
Is there any way to tell the diff in the 2 versions?

**UPDATE**
I noticed that you can make use of the `LoadFile` command in the Apache conf.
Adding `LoadFile <APACHE_ROOT>/HTTPServer/openldap/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2` in my 00-shib.conf file before the `LoadModule mod_shib /usr/lib64/shibboleth/mod_shib_24.so` entry resolved the issue.

This still seems like a workaround / hack to me and there may be an underlying issue with the libraries / different versions.